# How to configure multiple cells based on the data from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am have to show three different cells like (Facebook post) with all different size and design. The data is coming from server.What is the best way to deal with it. I have to use `UITableview` or `UICollectionview` there are three kinds of cells like:

1. News
2. Movies
3. Spots

Each cell type has different design, I want to identify each cell type from the data obtained from server and configure and display the correct cell.

The Cells Look Like This :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Implementation in both are almost same. so you can use either of it.

Comment: Do you want multiple cell in a row ? If That is the case, I recommend UICollectionView. Otherwise If you are using single cell in a row, using UITableView is better way.

Comment: I am using UICollection view from storyboard with number of items 3 (for news,movies,sports
 ) and with different Cell identifiers  but i am getting more feeds from server so i have to Identify the type by key from json @“news” i want to show correct cell with correct information.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, add as many prototype cells you need. Then, to each create a different identifier (and its own class). Shape each to how you want it to look.

Comment: Such kind of information should not be written as an answer. should be written as comment

Comment: Thanks for information. then in cellForItemAtIndexPath method i will find the type of cell.

Comment: Yes, for example: cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];

Comment: For what I see, there's no need for you to use UICollectionView... You will use a collectionView when you have more than one cell in row. In the image you have attached, you clearly have one cell per row, and in each just have different elements.

Comment: I am using UICollection view from storyboard with number of items 3 (for news,movies,sports ) and with different Cell identifiers but i am getting more feeds from server so i have to Identify the type by key from json @“news” i want to show correct cell with correct information

Comment: You don't need a collectionView. Use a tableView, with 3 prototype cells. create a custom tableviewcell classes for each of them, connect the lables, imageviews etc. what you receive from the server is irrelevant. You deal with it in a modal class. in the controller itself, you handle all of them together. You were asking UI perspective, and the answer is in the body of my answer and comments.